# On Linux, how to get the elapsed time for any shell command being executed?

Tags: command-line, time

I'm compiling a big project where it could take hours to build it. While the project is being compiled, I would like to view the time it has taken so far since the compilation was started.

There is a possibility to view the time after the compilation ends, but during the compilation is it possible to view the time?

Answer (score 2):

To see how long an already launched process has been running, you can use `ps -p {PID-HERE} -o etime` or `ps -p {PID-HERE} -o etimes`. For example, to check how long the process with PID (process ID) `123`
has been running, you would do:

```
 $ ps -p 123 -o etime
    ELAPSED
      00:21
```

or

```
$ ps -p 123 -o etimes
ELAPSED
     21
```

To time how long a process takes when launching it, use the `time` command. For example, `time sleep 1`:

```
$ time sleep 1

________________________________________________________
Executed in    1.00 secs      fish           external
   usr time   58.61 millis   58.61 millis    0.00 millis
   sys time   11.18 millis    8.59 millis    2.59 millis
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know for how long a process has been running, simply use [ps](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) with the `etime` format specifier for example :

```
ps -C command_name -o etime,args
```